# ASP.NET Core Identity Areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an interesting problem and Microsoft's documentation doesn't seem to cover it. I am creating an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and using authorization through the app, so you have to have permission to view the page, or some pages you just need to be logged into the application to access the page. That is all working correctly if you are logged in.

However with the Identity Area's they introduced on a user that is not logged in it redirects the user to: (If I manually add in /Identity/ it behaves normally.

"/Login/returnurl=something?something"

instead of

"/Identity/Login/returnUrl=something?something

Here is the startup file:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
            o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3));

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true; 
        });

        //These keys need to be setup on Azure or where you are running it to make it work.
        //services.AddAuthentication()
        //.AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
        //{
        //    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
        //    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
        //})
        //.AddGoogle(options =>
        //{
        //    IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
        //        Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

        //    options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
        //    options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
        //});
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just resolved the same problem adding these lines to the ConfigureServices.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I did see this posted on another post. But even with these lines it doesn't work. Does order matter of where it is inside of the configureServices? Seems anywhere I add it doesn't work. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact I am using MVC also. I added the full file my OG post.

Comment: Is the location of the above pages inside _/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account_ ?

Comment: I see what your thinking. The scaffolding of the folders is like that but the actual url is just /Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Ftracks%2Fupsert, if I try going to /Areas/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Ftracks%2Fupsert it gives me a 404 also.

Comment: No, the configuration path is OK without the Areas and Pages subfolders.  Just an idea, clear the cookies related to your localhost. Your ConfigureServices, with some minor differences is practically identical to mine. (Albeit my app is for Core3.0)

Comment: Wait, there is also this difference. _services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                        options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                    })_

Comment: Intresting, I added that in also no luck. With that do you have   services.ConfigureApplicationCookie stuff also?

Comment: Yes I have both but tried to remove the AddCookie part and it seems to be of no impact. If I type directly the name of a page that needs authorization the program correctly switch to the login page. Should be something different between 3.0 and 3.1. I am forced to stay with 3.0 by my ISP that doesn't have yet installed Core 3.1

Comment: Yeah it must be because with adding what you have it makes no difference. no ideas kind of stuck.